# Shake depending on on node_modules directory

Tags: shake-build-system

I am using Shake with an npm based project, but am baffled by how to handle the `node_modules` folder. The flow should be simple from what I can tell:

- Any change to `package.json` would cause `node_modules` to be re-populated.
- All the changes to `node_modules` and/or `main.ts` would cause a typescript related script to fire. In this case it would only run the once for the entire collection of changes.

How do I encode those dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `node_modules` is a directory rather than a file, and you [can't depend on directories](https://shakebuild.com/faq#how-can-i-depend-on-directories). The solution is to create a fake file, along the lines of:

```
"node_modules/.stamp" %> \out -> do
    need ["package.json"]
    cmd_ "npm update"
    copyFile' "package.json" out

"main.ts.out" %> \out -> do
    need ["node_modules/.stamp","main.ts"]
    cmd_ "whatever"
```

The only "weird" bit above is that we `copyFile'` the `package.json` for
our stamp file. That's a trick so that if we have hash-checking on the
files then the `.stamp` file changes, whereas if we always wrote `""` to
it then it wouldn't.