# Correct way to implement "yarn install" in shake-build?

Tags: shake-build-system

My question *might* be a duplicate of [Shake depending on on node_modules directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113136/shake-depending-on-on-node-modules-directory)

I'm new to shake-build and got stumped with the very first thing that I wanted to do. Basically, I want to run `yarn install` whenever the `yarn.lock` OR `package.json` file changes.

I tried the following first, but it ended up running *always*:

```hs
want ["foo"]

phony "foo" $ do
  need ["yarn.lock", "package.json"]
  cmd_ ["yarn", "install"]
```

Then I tried the following:

```hs
  want ["yarn.lock"]

  "yarn.lock" %> \out -> do
    need ["package.json"]
    cmd_ ["yarn", "install"]
```

And it *seems* to work, but not quite. It re-runs only when `yarn.lock` or `package.json` changes, but **fails to run** after an `rm -rf node_modules` (sadly, a very common occurence, btw!)

Is [Shake depending on on node_modules directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113136/shake-depending-on-on-node-modules-directory) the correct way to set this up? Does one have to resort to these fake files for all such cases? Shouldn't this be automagically handled somehow by the shake database?

**Edit:** As an extension to this question, what's the right way to setup a *common* rule that can do a `yarn install` in any given directory?

Answer (score 1):

For the first snippet, a `phony` rule is always rerun, so there's no point doing a `need` within it (unless it needs those outputs to do its job) - which explains why it was always rerun.

For the second snippet, you have said to build `yarn.lock` depend on `package.json`. It has no idea that the contents of `node_modules` are the important ones. To capture that, and be tolerant to `node_modules` being deleted, the stamp file approach works well.

The reason stamp files are necessary is that directories aren't really a tracked concept in Shake - they don't have identity, a good modification time, they don't have contents, they come and go freely in the build system. Adding a dependency on a directory always goes wrong sooner or later (Shake actually used to allow it).

For a common reusable rule, one approach is to encode the directory name in the stamp file (which I've named `.yarn_stamp`). For example:

```
"*.yarn_stamp" *> \out -> do
    let name = dropDirectory out
    need ["package.lock", name </> "package.json"]
    cmd_ "yarn install" (Cwd name)
    writeFile' out ""
```

As to whether this could be handled for you by Shake, very little goes deep into the Shake database - even the notion of files themselves are wrapped at a higher level. I looked at whether we could wrap the directory creation pattern, and it seems we're one simple function away from doing it - see https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/759 for that feature request (and please weigh in on the ticket if it seems useful for you).

Comment: So, IIUC, the rule should depend on THREE things to be correct - `package.json`, `yarn.lock`, AND `node_modules/`. But since this doesn't fit the model of "compile X to produce Y" (and therefore Y is the build target), we need to introduce a fake build target in the form of `.stamp` files. Am I right?

Comment: And the fake `.stamp` files are treated as the build target and they in-turn depend on the three things. But, do they? Will the `.stamp` approach work if I do `rm -rf node_modules/<specific-package>`. Will shake be able to detect the missing package and re-run `yarn install`?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, a better mental model is that `yarn.lock` actually determines what directories should be present **inside** `node_modules`. And `package.json` determines the contents of `yarn.lock`. Is this something that can be modelled in `shake`?

Comment: Reading the manual more carefully now - specifically https://shakebuild.com/manual#directory-listing-dependencies - I'm wondering if this could be setup by adding dependencies on `yarn.lock`, `package.json` AND all files inside `node_modules`. This would cover the following scenarios: (a) package is added/changed in package.json => will trigger the build (b) directory is removed from `node_modules` => will trigger the build. Is depending on a LARGE number of files in a directory problematic? Will it cause perf issues?

Comment: Most rules need to produce something, a specific named something. If every node_modules compilation produced a known `node_output_lump.js` or similar then that would work instead of a stamp file.

Your final comment about depending on the package.json, yarn.lock and the outputs is probably a reasonable thing to do, and works if you delete node_modules, however, the default directory listing functions assume they are working on source files. Depending on a large number of files/dirs will cause perf issues if it's enough, but it can cope with 10K, so probably not an issue.